# Calling a function every n seconds using TaskTimer

Tags: typescript, timer

I have a question about using classes in Typescript:

If I run this code (without classes)

```
var timer = new TaskTimer(1000);

function getData() {
    return Date.now();
}

function print1() {
    console.log(getData());
}

timer.add({
    id: 'job1',
    tickInterval: 2,
    totalRuns: 0,
    callback() {
        print1();
    }
});

// Start the timer
timer.start();
```

It works perfectly! But if I try to run the same code, only using classes, it throws me the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'print1' does not exist on type 'TaskCallback | ITaskOptions | Task | (TaskCallback | ITaskOptions | Task)[]'.
Property 'print1' does not exist on type 'TaskCallback'.
```

This is the code:

```
class App {

    timer: TaskTimer;

    constructor() {
        this.timer = new TaskTimer(1000);
    }

    getData() {
        return Date.now();
    }

    print1() {
        console.log(this.getData);
    }

    print2() {
        this.timer.add({
            id: 'job1',
            tickInterval: 1,
            totalRuns: 0,
            callback() {
                this.print1();
            }
        });

        this.timer.start();
    }
}

let app = new App();
app.print2();
```

What am I doing wrong in the second case? I may be to tired to figure it out, but right now I just don't get it...

Comment: Where does `TaskTimer` come from?

Comment: from here: [link](https://github.com/onury/tasktimer) I've used `import { TaskTimer } from 'tasktimer';` in both examples

Comment: I suspect that your `this` in the callback does not refer to the instance. Can you try with `const self = this` and then use self in the cb?

Comment: @k0pernikus Tried as you said and I've got rid of the error, but right now it's printing `[Function: getData]` instead of the current timestamp...

Comment: @k0pernikus If I'm using `console.log(self.getData());` in the callback instead of `self.print1();` it's printing correctly so... I'm guessing that now it's a problem with the `this` from the `print1()` function?

Comment: @k0pernikus I've tried to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` in the first place, but with no luck so I've given up on that and tried `TaskTimer`. This was my other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707022/print-timestamp-in-a-file-not-changing-timestamp-value) If you could have a look on it I would greatly appreciate it! :) (so far nobody answered...)

Comment: Try making the callback a bound function like `callback: () => this.print()`

Comment: @k0pernikus Ok. It was just a stupid mistake in the `print1()` function... I was using `this.getData` instead of `this.getData()`... Thanks a lot for the help!! :) Could you please explain a little more how is that the `this` that I was using in the callback was not referring to the right instance? Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: @user3063909 Don't ask follow-up questions within comments, ask a new questions. You can link to your old questions. That being said, in regards to `this` and its weird context, that's a growing pain of JavaScript itself and fills volumes. See this http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/ blogpost for example, esp. the part "What is “this” Context".

Comment: Also if you found your answer, don't point that out in a comment, but rather create your own answer. That perfectly fine and encouraged on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the callback using [object method shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) makes it an [unbound function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757407/bound-vs-unbound-functions):

```
            callback() {
                this.print1();
            }
```

In other words, from inside `callback` the `this` is not *necessarily* the class instance, but whatever the calling context is.

If you instead define the callback as a bound function ([fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) then `this` will be preserved as the class instance:

```
            callback: () => {
                this.print1();
            }
            // Or shorthand:
            callback: () => this.print1()
```